# Are there unique (untranslated) identifiers for Windows service names?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-services

I just wanted to "restart SharePoint" on one of our servers. So I quickly looked up which services need to be restarted to do that. Which lead me to a blog article that describes a [script to restart all SharePoint services](http://ochoco.blogspot.com/2009/03/script-to-restart-sharepoint-services.html).

Great. Sadly, the server isn't using the English language. So all I get are "The name of the service is unknown" error messages.

So, are there any identifiers I can use to refer to Windows services which are not translated?

I'm primarily interested in using these with `net start` and `net stop` (`sc` would work fine as well, I assume).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, every service has a *service name*, which is never translated. (The script in your link is using *display names*, which aren't intended to be used as identifiers.)

You can use `services.msc` or `sc query` to find out the service names. For example:

```
SERVICE_NAME: AudioSrv
DISPLAY_NAME: Windows Audio

SERVICE_NAME: Bonjour Service
DISPLAY_NAME: Bonjour Service
```

`sc` only accepts service names; `net` accepts both for compatibility reasons.